# ocean bathymetry in R

Tags: r

Im trying to make a bathymetry plot in R using library(oceanmap). I can't seem to resize the bathymetry plot. I tried to add.region as suggested in the oceanmap tutorial, but there was no window to resize! So im stuck with an overly large plot that cuts off at the bottom.

Anyone might know how I can resize get.bathy image?

```
library(oceanmap)

site <- extent(130,180,-80,-40)

par(mar=c(3, 2, 2, 2))
plotmap(site, grid=F, main="Southern Ocean")
bathy <- get.bathy(site, grid=F, cbpos='r', resolution=3)
```

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried plotting bathymetric `marmap` maps with `ggplot2`? The results are pretty decent in IMHO, and easily customizable:

```
library(marmap)
library(ggplot2)

data(florida)
autoplot(florida, geom = c("raster", "contour"), size=0.1) + 
  scale_fill_etopo()
```

Have a look at `?autoplot.bathy` and `?etopo.colors` for details and more examples.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I really don't mean to be "that guy", but there doesn't seem to be a good answer to this in any documentation or papers using oceanmap that I could find, so maybe you might want to look at marmap instead. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/marmap/vignettes/marmap-DataAnalysis.pdf is a really nice writeup on it, and the very first thing it shows you is a correctly scaled bathymetric map.

Comment: Thank you,I tried with marmap but its not as pretty..library(marmap)
SO <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = 130, lon2 = 180, lat1 = -80, lat2 = -40, resolution = 2)
summary(SO)

blues <- terrain.colors(10, alpha = 1)

greys <- c(grey(0.6), grey(0.93), grey(0.99))

plot(SO, image = TRUE, land = TRUE, lwd = 0.03,
     bpal = list(c(0, max(SO), greys),
                 c(min(SO), 0, blues)))
# Add coastline
plot(SO, n = 1, lwd = 0.4, add = TRUE)

Comment: I guess that's down to how deep you want to go in setting up colors manually for the map. It's definitely pretty ugly out of the box though.

Comment: Thats true. Im still trying to figure out how to make bathymetry plots. The oceanmap made them really nice! except for the life of me I can't resize it. All their examples came up perfect, when it came to my lat and long, it went all crazy..