# Plot a temperature profile with contours over distance and depth in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have seen in MATLAB some people plot temperature profiles INCLUDING CONTOURS intrapolated, over depth (y axis) and distance (x axis), like this :

[image]

I would like to know if there is something similar in R, having the data of temperature, distance and depth.

I have seen there is something such as bathymetry lines: [ocean bathymetry in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51827045/ocean-bathymetry-in-r)

I have created a random dataset, I would like to know if I could intrapolate the data and make it look less "squarey", and add the contour lines, I don't know if there is a special package for this either, but I wanted to try with ggplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
num_stations <- 10
depth_levels <- 201
set.seed(123)  

distance <- rep(1:num_stations, each = depth_levels)
depth <- rep(0:(depth_levels - 1), times = num_stations)

# Random temperature values for each station
temperature <- unlist(lapply(1:num_stations, function(station) {
  start_temp <- runif(1, 15, 25)  # Random starting temperature for each station
  depth_temp <- start_temp - cumsum(runif(depth_levels - 1, 0.1, 1.0))
  c(start_temp, depth_temp)
}))


data <- data.frame(Station = factor(distance), Depth = depth, Temperature = temperature)


ggplot(data, aes(x = distance, y = Depth, fill = Temperature)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") + 
  labs(x = "distance", y = "Depth (m)", fill = "Temperature (°C)") +
  theme_minimal()  + scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `geom_contour_filled`:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = distance, y = Depth)) +
  geom_contour_filled(aes(z = temperature), bins = 11) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
  labs(x = "distance", y = "Depth (m)", fill = "Temperature (°C)") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there a maximum number of bins you can create? or depending on the colour palette?

Comment: There's no maximum number of bins for all practical purposes. I chose 11 because that's how many are in the particular color palette I chose

Comment: Great many thanks! My concern is that when running it with my real dataset (5275 rows, 4329 unique temp. values); I get a white plot with the following error: ```Warning: [38;5;255m`stat_contour()`: Zero contours were generated[39m
Warning: no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning: no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf```. I checked and no missing values, distribution of data is poisson, tried to: reduce the number of rows, transforming temp. values, change number of bins... nothing worked, have you seen this type of warning before? or know how I could tackle it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to decide how you want to interpolate (I assume that's what you want and not "extrapolate").

```
data$distance <- distance    

library(interp)
data_p <- interp(data$distance, data$Depth, data$Temperature,
                 nx = 200, ny = 200, linear = TRUE)

ggplot(with(data_p, data.frame(x, y = rep(y, each = length(x)), z = c(z))), 
       aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = z)) +
  stat_contour(aes(z = z), color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") + 
  labs(x = "distance", y = "Depth (m)", fill = "Temperature (°C)") +
  theme_minimal()  + scale_y_reverse() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Super, thank you @Roland, yes, I probably meant interpolate. Thanks!